# Dataframe fillna() for datetime based on another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use .fillna to replace NaT data from another column, follows example:

| id | data1 | data2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-12 16:58:38.570 | 2021-02-12 17:30:55.000 |
| 2 | NaT | 2021-04-20 14:32:46.000 |

Expected:

| id | data1 | data2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-12 16:58:38.570 | 2021-02-12 17:30:55.000 |
| 2 | 2021-04-20 14:32:46.000 | 2021-04-20 14:32:46.000 |

I tried

```
df['data1'].fillna(df['data2'], inplace=True)
```

and nothing

Also tried

```
df['data1'] = df_final['data1'].replace('nan', np.nan).fillna(df['data2'], inplace=True)
```

but converted all of the data1 column to None

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's not actually NaT but a string `'NaT'`. So you could replace it with NaN, then could try `bfill` on axis:

```
df = df.replace('NaT', pd.NA).bfill(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  id                    data1                    data2
0  1  2021-02-12 16:58:38.570  2021-02-12 17:30:55.000
1  2  2021-04-20 14:32:46.000  2021-04-20 14:32:46.000
```

Comment: You're right, it was some sort of string, I run this df = df.replace('NaT', pd.NA) before what I was trying and replaced, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below function which will gives you better customization

```
def replaceNone(df):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row["data1"]==None:
            df.loc[index,"data1"] = row["data2"]
    return df
```